# Angular - Routes not working in production build

Tags: angular, angular-router

Routing in my app working perfectly in development mode, but when I serve my `dist` folder created by `ng build --prod` they don't work. I don't any error also while making the production build.
can someone guide me to the possible cause of this behavior ?

Here are the routes of my `app.routing.module`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./views/views.module').then(m => m.ViewsModule) },
];
```

here are the routes of my `views.routing.module`

```
const adminRoot = environment.adminRoot.substr(1); // path cannot start with a slash

let routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: adminRoot,
    loadChildren: () => import('./app/app.module').then((m) => m.AppModule),
    data: { roles: [UserRole.Admin, UserRole.Editor] },
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then((m) => m.UserModule),
  },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
  { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/error' },
];

if (!environment.isAuthGuardActive) {
  routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: 'app',
      loadChildren: () => import('./app/app.module').then((m) => m.AppModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'user',
      loadChildren: () =>
        import('./user/user.module').then((m) => m.UserModule),
    },
    { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/error' },
  ];
```

and here are the routes of another module

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: AppComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'vien' },
            { path: 'vien', loadChildren: () => import('./vien/vien.module').then(m => m.VienModule) },
            { path: 'second-menu', loadChildren: () => import('./second-menu/second-menu.module').then(m => m.SecondMenuModule) },
            { path: 'blank-page', component: BlankPageComponent },
            { path: 'product-list', component: ProductListComponent },
            { path: 'add-customer', component: AddCustomerComponent },
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: make sure your run it on  server .You can use http-server module to create local server

Comment: Please, check `--base-href` parameter.

More about this: https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: No console errors?